# Odoo practice beginner

Tags: python, xml, odoo

this is my modudel. it's installed and loaded without any errors.

1.need some help to figure out what is wrong with views because they don't show up.
2. how can i add menu in header and 2 sub menus on the left.

```
{
   'name' : "Helloworld",
   'version' : "1.0",
   'description' : 'Helloworld test module',
   'author' : "AP",
   'data' : ['helloworld_view.xml'],
   'installable' : True,
}





from openerp import models, fields



class HelloWorld(models.Model):
    _name = 'helloworld.test'

    name = fields.Char("Name", required=True, size=20 )
    value = fields.Integer("Value",  )

class HelloWorld2(models.Model):
    _name = "helloworld.test2"
    name = fields.Char("Name", required=True)
    reference = fields.Reference("helloworld.test")
```

this is view. I tried to attach it to Sales menu for now just to check but i definitely missing something. In general i want to have Helloworld menu in header and 2 sub menus Test and Test2 in left side when i click on header menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>

<openerp>
   <data>

    <record id= "helloworld_tree_view" model= "ir.ui.view">
     <field name="model">helloworld.test</field >
     <field name="arch" type= "xml">
         <tree>
             <field name="name"/>
             <field name="value"/>
         </tree>
   </field>
   </record>

   <record id= "helloworld_form_view" model= "ir.ui.view">
   <field name="model">helloworld.test</field >
   <field name="arch" type= "xml">
         <form>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="value"/>
         </form>
   </field>
   </record>

        <menuitem action= "helloworld_action"
            id="helloworld_menu_action"
            parent="base.menu_sales" sequence= "16" />

    <record id="helloworld_action" model= "ir.actions.act_window" >
            <field name="name" >Test1</field >
            <field name="type" >ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model" >helloworld.test</field >
            <field name="view_mode" >tree,kanban,form</field >
            <field name="view_type" >form</field >
            <field name="help" type= "html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create" >
                    Helloworld.
                </p>
            </field>
          </record>



   </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Which version of Odoo is it ?

Comment: Odoo 9.i tried to add header menu this way but still views not loading. <menuitem name="HelloWorld" id="helloworld_root_menu" sequence="450"/>
    
    <menuitem name="sub_menu_test1" id="sub_menu_test1" parent="helloworld_root_menu" sequence="5"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about how you wrote your `__openerp__.py` but you are not importing your views, of that I'm sure.

All the records of your views are written without names (that field is mandatory, your code should throw an error).

If you revise your `__openerp__.py` file, it should work (provided you name your views).

```
{
    'name' : "Helloworld",
    'summary': "Helloworld",
    'version' : "1.0",
    'description' : 'Helloworld test module',
    'author' : "AP",
    'depends': ['base', 'sale'],
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'data' : ['helloworld_view.xml'],
    'installable' : True,
}
```

Then in your `helloworld_view.xml` (make sure that file is at the root of your project and that it is named **exactly** like this), views should be like these (with the field name set)

```
<record id= "helloworld_tree_view" model= "ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">helloworld.tree.view</field>
    <field name="model">helloworld.test</field >
    <field name="arch" type= "xml">
        <tree>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="value"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

And don't use fields.Reference. Use `fields.Many2one`.

**EDIT**

Ah and one last thing. You should write your menuitem after the definition of the action. Otherwise it will not find it and will tell you that the external ID does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In `<menuitem>` if you will give parent then that menu will be add under that menu.

To add menu in Header then create menu without parent.

In your case, to add Test1 under Helloworld, you can try as following.

```
 <menuitem 
            id="helloworld_menu_action"
            sequence= "16" name="Hello World" string="Hello World"/>
 <menuitem action= "helloworld_action"
            id="menu_helloworld_test"
            parent="helloworld_menu_action"
            sequence= "16" />
```

**NOTE**

Please give parameter **action** in `<menuitem>` as I have given in example, otherwise menu will not display and view will not load.

Comment: I tried this but still no menus showing up. they are not loading when i start server.  maybe i missing something in __openerp__.py ?